# ios how can I deselect game center and in-app-purchase when I try to register my app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes

I'm trying to register my app in the apple developer portal but there you can select the services your app is going to be using. by my problem is I'm not going to be using:"game center" or "in-app-purchase". How can I deselect those?

[image]

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no need to deselect those options. Just because they are selected doesn't mean your app has to use those features.

Comment: Think these 2 options as added library for iOS apps which can be used if you include in your app (and also make some setup in itunesconnect) but if you dont use it, it wont hurt. These options are selected by default as Apple wrote here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578-CH1-IOS_PROVISIONING_PORTAL

Comment: It's true that you don't have to use them, but it causes the app to show a tag in the App Store which indicates that it uses in-app purchase.  I turned it on a while back on my app but never actually used it and now I can't turn it off.  I think being flagged as using in-app purchases may be viewed as undesirable by some purchasers and wish I could turn it off.

Comment: 9 years later and this is still a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Wildcard App ID`

As indicated in the `Registering an App ID` page:

> **App ID Suffix**
>
> *Explicit App ID*
>
> If you plan to incorporate app services such as Game Center, In-App Purchase, Data Protection, and iCloud, or want a provisioning profile unique to a single app, you must register an explicit App ID for your app.
>
> To create an explicit App ID, enter a unique string in the Bundle ID field. This string should match the Bundle ID of your app.
>
> *Wildcard App ID*
>
> This allows you to use a single App ID to match multiple apps. To create a wildcard App ID, enter an asterisk (*) as the last digit in the Bundle ID field.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to publish my app for testFlight, and the form to create an app in iTunes Connect requires to use an explicit AppID. :-/

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to disable Game Center and In-app purchases, but not sure about the implications and also not sure how long this will work. So use it at your own risk.

Basically enter an invalid bundle identifier, if you have other identifiers(or something like com.test.test), you can use that and click on Continue. This refreshes the page showing an error, but this also now allows unchecking of Game Center and In-app purchases.

Comment: I was also able to do this by just selecting the wild card option, then reselecting explicit

Answer (score -4):

You have to "enable restrictions" before you can use them.  Disabling in-app purchases is considered a restriction.

Comment: Not relevant. The question is for configuring an app on the app store. Restrictions only apply to the end user.