# Apple developer account: cannot turn off in-app purchase

Tags: ios, iphone

I find it weird already, and i hope i am missing something.

I have an App with in-app purchase OFF in capabilities.

[image: OFF in Capabilities]

In iTunes My Apps / Features there is NO product (i removed it).
[image: existing products in Features: empty.]

BUT on my developer account, certificates / app ids, the In-App purchase is still enabled and CANNOT be unchecked.
[image: developer account: in-app cannot be unchecked]

The reviewers had it Rejected already several times despite my descriptions of the problem (in resolution center) and messages to the App Review Board.

Notes:

1. A previous reviewed build had use in-app purchase.
2. The app was never published yet.
3. Cause of rejection: "(...) we are not able to continue because we cannot locate the in-app purchases within
   your app."

Thnx,

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913115/ios-how-can-i-deselect-game-center-and-in-app-purchase-when-i-try-to-register-my .. My Apps do have In-App Purchase and Game Center selected too and I've never had any issue releasing it.

Comment: I am taking this more accurately here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325504/apple-in-app-subscription-information-missing-but-no-in-app-purchase-used too (another way to ask it)