# apple in-app subscription information missing but NO in-app purchase used

Tags: ios, review

a. I removed all the in-app purchase products. Its empty. (there was an Auto-Renewable Subscription)
b. My app (not published yet) has in-app purchase OFF too (in capabilities).

Anyway, in subscription groups, one is there and i cannot delete it: I just don't find the way or it simply can't be removed.

But above that, the app is being rejected "because we cannot locate the in-app purchases within your app." and they also mention missing information related to the subscription.

Anyhow, they don't realise that the App does not use it or something is confusing them.

any clues??
[image: No in-app purchase, subscription group still there.]

EDIT: Answer from review board today:

"However, you have not deleted the In-App Purchase products; they are still attached to the binary. 
Please delete the In-App Purchase products from iTunes Connect, then resubmit your binary, so that we may continue the review."

And they sent this link: [Delete an in-app purchase](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deve4e779617)

Well, what else, as you can see in the screenshots I had already deleted  the product before sending the new build...

I am starting to think that maybe they need weeks to update its status?

Comment: Do you have the IAP attached to a presubmission release?

Check in App Store > iOS App > 1.0 Pepare for Submission and scroll down, you may have added it to your release already and that is where it is getting stuck.

Comment: @JacobEiting you gave me some hope :) but the app was not released yet. I edited with a board answer from today.. I did look up also where you mention without finding any reference to the in-app purchase.. I am missing something here?